# Is there an adjective for deer-like?

Tags: single-word-requests, animals

"Canine" is for dog, "Porcine" for pig, "Equine" for horse. Is there an adjective for deer-like?

Comment: I totally agree with Glorfindels answer, but if you are looking for a word that is understood by the vast majority of people, there is nothing wrong with just using "deer-like"  as an adjective. And that goes for more from Latin derived similar words. Most people would probably associate Porcine with porcupines in stead of pigs. Canine is really well-known, but others much less so. Equine (and Bovine) are sort of in between. Many people will know the word, while others go "WTF?" if you use it.

Answer (score 54):

*cervine*

> of, relating to, or resembling deer

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cervine))

With words like these, it sometimes helps if you look up the animal in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deer), check what the Latin-based family name is (*cervinae*), and look for similar words in a dictionary.

Comment: thanks for that. I've never heard that use in common (American) usage, have you ever come across it in writing or spoken yourself?

Comment: No, but neither have I encountered *porcine*.

Comment: I think I've heard it sometimes in medical articles: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2013/728791/. "Swine flu" and all that's related to that.

Comment: Your last para is very much  "give a fishhook instead of a fish", and I thought the best part of your answer. +1

Comment: Buy an old paperback Latin dictionary. There are dozens of them and they're cheap. They also don't go out of style. If you want a technical term, look up the Latin word for what you want and then check that in an English dictionary. Chances are you'll find it.

Comment: There's also *ovine* for sheep, *hircine* for goats (some Elder Scrolls fans just had a moment of epiphany reading that), *piscine* for fish, as well as more well-known ones, *feline* and *serpentine* should need no explanation.

Comment: It's not *common* but I've heard and used the word *cervine* before in technical contexts.

Comment: Common knowledge of latin terms seems to go with how common/cool the animal is. Feline, canine, bovine, equine since those animals are everywhere. Lupine since wolves are cool. Porcine since pig is a good insult. Ovine somewhat so we can call conformists sheep-like, ditto Ursine for big, hairy men. But deer are less common and we rarely want to call someone deer-like.

Comment: @OwenReynolds I have never heard Porcine, Ovine, Ursine in common usage

Comment: The Wikipedia article may even just give the appropriate adjective – the [Pig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig) page, for example, has the Latin family name _Suidae_ but the Etymology section notes that "an adjectival form is porcine". (edit: Actually, the [Deer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deer) article also states "the adjective of relation is cervine" in its Etymology and Terminology section)

Comment: I like *murine*.

Comment: @SomeGuy One might read about a porcine sheriff or mother-in-law, or a clever news article may use "pig" twice and then "porcine" to mix it up. Fantasy novels have warriors of ursine physiques (and everyone knows Ursa major is the big bear), Dungeons&Dragons bear-people are called Ursines. I knew ovine from memory but had to double-check -- maybe a cartoon wolf said it to a sheepdog as they punched the clock.

Comment: You're reaching into the realm of the implausible with the last example, but ok @OwenReynolds

Comment: Sometimes you need to dig deeper and look at Greek... _taurine_ for “bull-like”.

Comment: @JohnLawler Something I've noticed is that the vast majority of Latin words can also be used as proper English words. It's as if they are intrinsically "acceptable"

Answer (score 6):

"***Deerlike***" is a dictionary word (which also happens to be an adjective):

> (in British English)
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> - resembling a deer

([Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deerlike))

However, [*cervine*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/563565/356843) appears to be used more frequently than *deerlike*:

> [image]
>
> [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cervine%2C+deerlike&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccervine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeerlike%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccervine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeerlike%3B%2Cc0)

---

You could also use:

**[Even-toed] Ungulate**

> Ungulates (pronounced /ˈʌŋɡjəleɪts/ UNG-gyə-layts) are members of a
> diverse clade of primarily large mammals with hooves.
>
> The term means, roughly, "being hoofed" or "hoofed animal".

There are two types of ungulates:

> - [*Odd-toed ungulates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd-toed_ungulate) such as horses, rhinoceroses and tapirs.
> - [*Even-toed ungulates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-toed_ungulate) such as cattle, pigs, giraffes, camels, sheep,  *deer*, and hippopotamuses.
>
> [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungulate)

Hence, "*deerlike*" mammals can also be referred to as "*even-toed ungulates*".

Note that this is a general term and can apply to other hoofed mammals too..

---

Comment: Ungulates (even if you restrict it to "even-toed") includes so many things that are *not* deer, it might be too general to be of use in this situation.